# Relation between $\operatorname{Prob}(X+Y)$ and $\operatorname{Prob}(X)+\operatorname{Prob}(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables on the same probability space $(\mathbb N_0,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$.
Under what conditions on $X$ and $Y$ can I say something about the relation between the following two sides?

$$\mathbb P(X+Y = x+y)\quad \substack{\geq \\ \leq} \quad \mathbb P(X=x) + \mathbb P(Y=y)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all random variables you can say $P(X+Y \leq x+y) \leq P(X\leq x) + P(Y \leq y)$ which
is not quite what you are looking for. On the other hand, if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly continuous random variables, then 
$$P(X+Y = x+y) = 0 = P(X=x)+P(Y=y) ~~\mathrm{for~all} ~ x ~\mathrm{and}~ y.$$

---

But if $\mathbb N_0$ means that $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative integer-valued
random variables, then consider the simplest case when they are 
Bernoulli random variables with parameter $\frac{1}{2}$.

- If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and
  we take $x=y=1$, we have
  $$P(X+Y=1+1) = P(X=1,Y=1) = 0.25 < P(X=1)+P(Y=1) = 1,$$ but if
  we take $x=1.25, y = 0.75$, then
  $$P(X+Y = x+y)=P(X+Y=2) = 0.25 > P(X= 1.25)+P(Y=0.75) = 0.$$
- If instead of being independent, we have $X=1-Y$ and we take 
  $x = 1, y = 0$, we get 
  $$P(X+Y = 1+0) = P(X+Y=1) = 1 = P(X=1)+P(Y=0) =0.5+0.5$$

Comment: Thanks! Something like the first relation was what I was looking for. The second one is a reformulation of a single point in a continuous distribution having zero measure, or is there any more information to it?

Comment: @Did Thanks for fixing the typo caused by my sheer carelessness in not looking at the MathJax output, and for the upvote.